Does 4d contraction exist?
4d due to having a higher principle quantum number and being a d orbital should have less shielding effect than 3d and since 3d contraction exists due to the poor shielding of 3d electrons 4d contraction also must exist with a more significant effect. To test this I checked the values of atomic radii at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius and according to the empirical values 4d contraction shows a similar effect as 3d contraction. But, when I asked my teacher he said that no such effect exists and contraction due to 4d is the same as normal contraction. As such I came here to confirm, does 4d contraction exist? Also, using a similar argument 4f contraction must also exist, does it?

I am not sure, but lanthanide contraction and d-block contraction exist.

I am aware of those effects
